# How to change datasource of dropdown in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, client-side

I am looking to change to list items available in a dropdownlist via jquery (using razor in MVC3).

I have a DDL that is populated from view data;

```
@Html.DropDownList("allusers", null, null, new { @class = "chosenlist" })
```

There is also another set of viewdata called "allNewUsers". I have a button that is clicked that runs a bit of clientside jquery:

```
   $(function() {
    $('#remove').click(function () {
        var id = $("#allusers").val();
        var hdr = $("#Holdersid").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "RemoveApprover/" + id + "/" + hdr + "/3",
            data: id,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#remove').hide();
               $..change view data here
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {  
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        })
    })
    });
```

This code runs a public string back on the server and on success hides the remove button. What I then need to do is change the datasource of the DDL from allusers to allNewusers. can I do this easily in my client side code?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep the allNewUsers viewdata in a `hidden` control. On button click clear the list in the `dropdown` and Loopthrough the hidden control viewdata and append to the `dropdown` list via `jQuery`.